# Display info on listview from 2 (or more) tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, listview

There is way to populate ListView from 2 (or more) tables that not connected one to other?

Example:
I have 2 tables:

> firstTable , secTable

each table include different columns.. ex:

> firstTable include: id, name, city, display (bit)
>
> SecondTable include: id, name, country , display (bit)

- The tables already used in site so it cant be change their counstractour

I want to display in List View

> name (from firstTable)
>
> name(from SecondTable)
>
> Where display = True

I've been tried to do that with SqlDataSource without success.

The details on the listview display on seperate blocks (like news blocks).

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with SqlDataSource but the Selectcommand should use statement like:

```
 Select f.name, s.name from firstTbl as f inner join secondTbl as s on f.ID = s.ID 
                       where f.display='true'
```